# EF: Clear Collection Property without First Getting Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class called `Facility`.  `Facility` has a collection property on it called `Employees`.  I'm using the disconnected layer of EF.  I want to clear the `Employees` collection from a specific facility, but I don't want to make two trips to the DB: (1) getting all the employees, and then (2) clearing the.  How can I do this?

Here's what I've tried...

```
Facility f = new Facility()
{
    Id = 4,
    Employees = new List<Employee>()
};
context.Facilities.Attach(f);
context.Entry<Facility>(f).Collection(fac => fac.Employees).IsLoaded = true;

context.SaveChanges();
```

I think I'm close, but it doesn't work.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `Employees` entity has a FK property to `Facility`, right?. What do you want to do with the related employees, delete them?. Could you post your entities?

Comment: I don't want to delete the employees.  I just want to clear the relationship; therefore, I want to keep my current employees as well as my facility, but I want to clear the employees FROM the facility.  In essence, it will look like a new facility.

Comment: And the relationship between `Employees` and Facility is optional? In other words, `FacilityId` FK in `Employees` allows null values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use EF only, you're always going to need *some* roundtrip. In the end, EF needs to generate `DELETE ... WHERE Id = x` statements. How would it know the values for `x` without first grabbing them from the database?

But of course you can do this in a more efficient way than fetching the complete `Employee` objects. It's enough to get the `Id` values. Then you can use these `Id`s to create *stub entities* that you mark as `Deleted`:

```
var ids = context.Empoyees.Where(e => e.FacilityId == 4)
                 .Select(e => e.Id).ToArray();

foreach(int id in ids)
{
    var emp = new Empoyee { Id = id }; // Stub entity
    context.Entry(emp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

This is pure EF. But you can also use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). This allows you to execute a statement like

```
context.Empoyees.Where(e => e.FacilityId == 4)
       .Delete();
```